# How to sense if a certain area of an Html Canvas is clicked

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I am making a game on a canvas which requires clicking a certain area of a canvas.

I need to find a way to find the coordinates of a mouse and how to sense if a cartain area is clicked.
i want a command that looks like this:

```
    if(MouseX>20 && MouseX<40 && MouseY >20 && MouseY <40 && MouseClick==true){
alert("you clicked this area");
}
```

Comment: So have you looked into what details are available via the `event` object when a click event occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an event listener for your mouse move and track you x and y coordinate. Another listener will could be created for the click event and that is when you can access if the click was in a certain location.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jeremythuff/mgm5m5mp/5/)

```
var mousePos = {
    x: null,
  y: null
}

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
    mousePos.x = e.clientX;
  mousePos.y = e.clientY;
});

document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    console.log(mousePos);
});
```

Both listeners are not strictly necessary, since the clientX and clientY are both on the event of the click, but I find that it is usually good to know the location of the mouse even when the button has not just been clicked.

**UPDATE**

I am used to dealing with full screen canvases, but it is true that the code I have put here will only give you mouse position on the document and not the canvas. .layerX and .layerY on the event object will give you the position relative to your element.

Comment: Why do you need a mouse move handler when the click event object includes the clientX and Y properties?

Comment: Updated my answer to take this into account. And you are right it is not necessary. It often becomes important if you want to start addressing things like drag events.

Comment: Also, his question asked both for the coordinates of the mouse and the location when clicked.

Comment: @Jeremythuff and you are only getting the coordinates relative to the page, not to the canvas matrix.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested just in canvas area, use this cross-browser code:

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var MouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft; 
    var MouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
});
```